# Wordpress/ACF: Posts related to author

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need a list, in wp-admin, on the profile page, which lists all the users posts. Not just post_type `post`, but also with `author` with the current user ID.

I've set the relationshop to the post_type, but isn't it possible to make another "meta query" of some sort, so I can chose only to show the current users posts?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create an [ACF relationshop query](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-relationship-query/).

```
function profile_relationship_query( $args, $field, $post_id ) {
    $post_type = $args["post_type"][0];

    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'post_type'   => $post_type,
        'meta_query'  => array (
            array (
                'key'     => 'authors',
                'value'   => '"' . $post_id . '"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );

    return $args;
}
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=profile_articles', 'profile_relationship_query', 10, 3);
```

And add it to `functions.php`.